# Py2Exe generate log file

Tags: python, logging, py2exe, distutils

My problem is that `py2exe` is generating a log file when I run. It doesn't generate because I have an error when running the program. At the log file there is the standard console print out!

How can I do it that no log file would generate?

here my py2exe setup code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "run.py"}],
    zipfile = None
)
```

Comment: You should include the error traceback too.

Comment: there is no error!
I just want to disable the log-file...

Comment: You can set `sys.stdout = os.devnull` in your script -- or do the equivalent via command-line redirection.

Comment: Dont work. I set your code to the beginning of the file... and it still produce a log file: [I 13-12-12 18:40:12] >>> starting FTP server on 127.0.0.1:21, pid=2508 <<<
[I 13-12-12 18:40:12] poller: <class 'pyftpdlib.ioloop.Select'>
[I 13-12-12 18:40:12] masquerade (NAT) address: None
[I 13-12-12 18:40:12] passive ports: None

Comment: Try using `sys.stderr = sys.stdout = os.devnull`. (Also note that for me to be notified of your response, you need to put @martineau somewhere in your comment).

Comment: All doesn't worked. Can i just remove the file from py2exe? (boot_common.py)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GUI applications, Py2exe redirects `sys.stderr` to a log file and `sys.stdout` to an object that ignores all writes. To avoid the log file, do this in your program at the top of the main module:

```
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
```

Or, let py2exe create a console application by using the `console` keyword instead of `windows` in `setup.py`.

Comment: at the setup file or at my program?

Comment: All doesn't worked.
Can i just remove the file from py2exe? (boot_common.py)?

Comment: @user3096402 According to the comments in boot_common.py, some redirection is necessary to avoid an exception that is eventually caused by writing to the default stderr.

Comment: what exact must i do?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can remove the content of the file! It can work, but you must see if your programm needs some function defined there and then it can get errors!

Answer (score -1):

At the chat you said that you want to use Python 3 but Py2Exe isn't there... Why don't you use cx_Freeze? It generates a bin and an .exe file. You can make an Installation with InnoSetup and you Game is perfect!